# How do I run a executable jar file on cloudbees (eg spring-boot)

Tags: spring, jvm, cloudbees, spring-boot

I'm testing out Spring Boot and was trying to upload a Spring Boot JAR to CloudBees using the JVM Runtime Container.

The preferred packaging for Spring Boot apps is a JAR file that can be run with the "java -jar" command line option.

I was unable to upload one of these JARs to RUN@Cloud and ended up creating a ZIP file containing the various JARs and setting classpath, etc. This required me to create a custom build script for CloudBees rather than a post processor that just uploaded the JAR as built by the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin.

It would be nice if RUN@Cloud, the "bees" command and documentation were updated to provide support for single-jar apps that are started with "java -jar", is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload a jar with the java stack but you still need to specify the class and classpath (http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container). The java container does not currently use "java -jar"

Example:

```
bees app:deploy -t java -R java_version=1.7         
 -R class=org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher app.jar
```

An example repo:

https://github.com/msgilligan/springboot-cloudbees-hello

Comment: Actually, the 'classpath' parameter is incorrect (apparently because as a single-jar app it's redundant) and results in a non-fatal error in the server log.  It should be removed from the app:deploy command.